# Passing variables from --extra-vars into roles

Tags: azure, ansible

I have a role to provision Azure vm's my main objective is to pass vm image name as a parameter through --extra var

my playbook is defined like this :

```
- hosts: localhosts
  gather_facts:yes
  roles: 
    -azurevm
```

The role is defined like this (in `azurevm.yml`)

```
  - name: create a vm
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      name: "{{vm_name}}"
```

the defaults have

```
vm_name : imagevm
```

I want to overwrite vm_name in this case to take value from cli. Any idea how we do that ?

Comment: The answer is in your title: pass the var as extra var to your playbook. It will override the defaults from role. See [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). `extra-vars` always win.

Comment: @Zeitounator i did that but vm_name was not read.

Comment: Then you probably did not do it the good way. See my answer below for a quickNdirty functional example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use that var as an extra var, it will override the default var in role.

Note that according to [ansible variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#ansible-variable-precedence) role default vars are the second most overridable vars after command line options (not to confuse with extra_vars which always win). So the example is with `extra_vars` as requested, but this would also work overriding the var anywhere (machine/group inventory var, playbook...)

Here is a quickNdirty POC to show you the way:

## File structure

```
.
├── playbook.yml
└── roles
    └── test
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main.yml
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml
```

## `roles/test/tasks/main.yml`

```
---
- name: Show value of vm_name
  debug:
    var: vm_name
```

## `roles/test/defaults/main.yml`

```
---
vm_name: imagevm
```

## `playbook.yml`

```
---
- name: demonstrate overriding role default
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  roles:
    - role: test
```

## Results

### Default value

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [demonstrate overriding role default] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test : Show value of vm_name] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vm_name": "imagevm"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

### Override value with `extra_vars`

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e vm_name=overrideName

PLAY [demonstrate overriding role default] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test : Show value of vm_name] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vm_name": "overrideName"
}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```